# While pressing any key Button gets visible of Password field(function like Instagram's login page)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, keyboard-events

I tried to make clone of Instagram's login page. I tried to copy "Show Button"(in password field) functionality like this:

```
const input = document.querySelector('.password');
input.addEventListener('keydown', showButton);

function showButton(e) {
    button.style.display = "block";
}
```

Problem with the code is, that its also working on pressing keys like - shift,alt,ctrl etc.
i wanted to work it only on alphabetic and numeric keys which are most likely to be filled in input of type-password, so then user can see the button(Show) to see the password.

Comment: Options: 1. Change event to `input` or `change`. 2. Add check for key codes and decide when to do it.

Comment: Thanks by changing event to input its now working as i wanted,
but not with 'change'
I tried event change few minutes ago, but didn't know about 'input'
But Thanks